# Cast double to int64_t and back without info lost

Tags: c++, c++17

This question has probably being asked, but I searched and could not find the answer.

I'm implementing a toy virtual machine, where the OpCodes take the form:

```
std::tuple<int8_t, int64_t, int64_t> // instruction op1, op2
```

I'm trying to pack a double into one of the operands and read it back again when processing it. This doesn't work reliably.

```
double d = ...
auto a = static_cast<int64_t>(d);
auto b = static_cast<double>(a)
// sometimes, b != d
```

Is there a way to pack the bit representation of the double into an int64_t, and then read that bit pattern back get the same exact double as before?

Comment: The questions that have been asked are probably http://stackoverflow.com/q/2544394/11683, discussing what you currently have, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/103868/11683, discussing what you probably want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to reinterpret\_cast an integer to float?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982340/is-it-safe-to-reinterpret-cast-an-integer-to-float)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static_cast` performs a value conversion - the fractionary part is always lost. `memcpy` is what you are after.

```
double d = ... 
int64_t a;
memcpy(&a, &d, sizeof(a));
double d2;
memcpy(&d2, &a, sizeof(d2));
```

Still, I would probably instead make the operands a `union` with a `double` and an `int64_t` (plus possibly other types that are interesting for your VM).

Comment: It is undefined behaviour to read from any member of a union except for the last one written.

Comment: @RichardCritten I assume the suggestion is that if a `double` parameter is intended, then it will be both written and read as `double`  (with the `int8_t` member of the tuple being used to discriminate)

Comment: Exactly as M.M said.

Answer (score 1):

One way to make it work is to reinterpret the block of memory as int64_t/double, i.e. to do pointer casts:

```
double d = ...
auto *a = (int64_t*)&d;
auto *d2 = (double*)a;
auto b = *d2;
assert(d == b);
```

Note that we both assume here that `double` and `int64_t` are of the same size (64 bit). I don't remember now if it is a part of the standard.

Comment: Btw, you can do that even without pointers: `int64_t a = (int64_t &)d;`.

Comment: This is Undefined Behaviour.  std::memcpy is the only defined way.

Comment: @RichardCritten Why is it UB? I mean as long as sizes are correct then what's undefined about it?

Comment: @freakish because the standard says so, you would need to check to see if a compiler supported an extension.  _"... and it's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written. Many compilers implement, as a non-standard language extension, the ability to read inactive members of a union."_  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

Comment: @RichardCritten Why are you talking about unions? How is that related to pointer casts with the same size?

Comment: @freakish This is well defined to cast to another pointer type and back. What is Implentation Defined is when you try to read the value of different pointer type. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7832859/5405086. It's not UB!